# jQuery Keep Document at bottom of scroll always

Tags: jquery, scroll

How can I make sure the scroller is always all the way down?

What I use now is this: `$('html,body').prop('scrollTop',$(document).height());`.

The problem is that there are lots of floating elements and it won't scroll to the bottom of the document until a clearing element is inserted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(100000000000000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

We do this by using the jquery auto scroll plugin. Check it out. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/aautoscroll

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...onRowAdded = function() {
$('#myTable').animate({scrollTop: $('#myTable').attr('scrollHeight')});
```

};